# How to change textview shadow color for onclick

Tags: android, textview, shadow

is thr any way to change textview text shadow color

simillar to changing text color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- focused and pressed -->
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:color="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
```

Comment: Why don't you create a style and apply it in your item in the above selector.

Comment: can u send me a sample?

Comment: "Selector works only for drawables, not text appearances"

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7706405/1479968

Answer (score 1):

**Create a style in `styles.xml`**

```
<style name="myshadowstyle">   
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#ff8800</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

Now in your **selector xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item style="@style/myshadowstyle" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->
<item style="@style/myshadowstyle" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- focused and pressed -->
<item style="@style/myshadowstyle" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: i have integrated but the border doesn't apply

Comment: what border are you talking about do you get the text shadow ?

Comment: yeah  i need to get the text shadow

Comment: Did you apply the above code - if yes , then what is difference between your previous selector and this one.

Comment: text shadow has not apply . i need it apply for the onclick also

Comment: Look at my edit I have edited the **selector xml** file, try this.

Comment: here is my code  -
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/main_screen_sample_row_text"
        android:textColor="@layout/list_row_text_selector"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select"/> <!-- focused and pressed --><item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/black" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>

Comment: what is inside main_screen_shadow_select

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select"/> <!-- focused and pressed --><item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/black" style="@style/main_screen_shadow_select"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29826/discussion-between-pks-and-mr-g)

Comment: I mean what is inside your styles.xml that is the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, Color.GRAY);
```